# The quote box will go down and up as per the scrolling of the home page.

Tags: html

The quote box will go down and up as per the scrolling of the home page.

http://cybernician.co.in/medical2/index.html

Comment: So whats the question?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want it to be fixed...so: `position: fixed;` may help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your quote box css is like this

```
#quote-icon{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
}
```

Try and add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
var top = $('#quote-icon').offset().top - parseFloat($('#quote-icon').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    //if y > top, it means that if we scroll down any more, parts of our element will be outside the viewport
    //so we move the element down so that it remains in view.
    if (y >= top) {
       var difference = y - top;
       $('#quote-icon').css("top",difference);
   }
 });
});
</script>
```